# Unable to get Response from AA control room

Tags: automationanywhere

I am getting the following error in Postman 
404 - File or directory not found. with HTML while hitting the AA Control room API.

Answer (score 0):

We have found this issue is caused by too many dependencies. We aren't sure yet if it is too many in the control room or too many for the process however we have been able to fix it by deleting the process from the control room repository and re-uploading it to the repository.

Comment: even I am getting this, but do we have any concrete answer from AA Support?